# Add alt and title tags to images with the help of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, blogger, feed

I have this script that uses the blogger feed to pull the content.

It pulls text and image from the article.

It would be perfect if the Alt and Title tags were added to the images, does anyone have any idea how to do this?

```
<div id="feed-list-container">
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">
</div>

<style>
div[data-tag=''] {float: left;

    positon: relative;
    width: 26%;

    background-color: #9cb5c2;
}

</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var multiFeed = {
    feedsUri: [

        {
            name: "Terror",
            url: "https://elfenliedbrazil.blogspot.com/",
            tag: "Terror"
        },

    ],
    numPost: 18,
    showThumbnail: true,
    showSummary: true,
    summaryLength: 200,
    titleLength:"auto",
    thumbSize: 200,
    containerId: "feed-list-container",
    readMore: {
        text: "",
        endParam: "?max-results=20"
    }
};
</script>
```

This is my code so far:

```
var mf_defaults = {
  feedsUri: [{
    name: "Posting JQuery",
    url: " ",
    tag: "JQuery"
  }, {
    name: "Posting CSS",
    url: "",
    tag: "CSS"
  }, {
    name: "Widget-Widget Blogger",
    url: " ",
    tag: "Widget"
  }],
  numPost: 4,
  showThumbnail: true,
  showSummary: true,
  summaryLength: 80,
  titleLength: "auto",
  thumbSize: 200,
  thumbWidth: 200, // new setting
  thumbHeight: 90, // new setting
  newTabLink: false,
  containerId: "feed-list-container",
  listClass: "list-entries",
  readMore: {
    text: "More",
    endParam: "?max-results=20"
  },
  autoHeight: false,
  current: 0,
  onLoadFeed: function(a) {},
  onLoadComplete: function() {},
  loadFeed: function(c) {
    var d = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
      a = document.getElementById(this.containerId),
      b = document.createElement("script");
    b.type = "text/javascript";
    b.src = this.feedsUri[c].url + "/feeds/posts/summary" + (this.feedsUri[c].tag ? "/-/" + this.feedsUri[c].tag : "") + "?alt=json-in-script&max-results=" + this.numPost + "&callback=listEntries";
    d.appendChild(b)
  }
};
for(var i in mf_defaults) {
  mf_defaults[i] = (typeof(multiFeed[i]) !== undefined && typeof(multiFeed[i]) !== "undefined") ? multiFeed[i] : mf_defaults[i]
}

function listEntries(q) {
  var p = q.feed.entry,
    c = mf_defaults,
    h = document.getElementById(c.containerId),
    a = document.createElement("div"),
    d = "",
    l = c.feedsUri.length,
    n, k, m, g;
  for(var f = 0; f < c.numPost; f++) {
    if(f == p.length) {
      break
    }
    n = (c.titleLength !== "auto") ? p[f].title.$t.substring(0, c.titleLength) + (c.titleLength < p[f].title.$t.length ? "&hellip;" : "") : p[f].title.$t;
    m = ("summary" in p[f]) ? p[f].summary.$t.replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, " ").replace(/<.*?>/g, "").replace(/[<>]/g, "") : "";
    m = (c.summaryLength < m.length) ? m.substring(0, c.summaryLength) + "&hellip;" : m;
    g = ("media$thumbnail" in p[f]) ? '<img src="' + p[f].media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s72(\-c)?\//, "/w" + c.thumbWidth + "-h" + c.thumbHeight + "-c/") + '" style="width:' + c.thumbWidth + "px;height:" + c.thumbHeight + 'px;">' : '';
    for(var e = 0, b = p[f].link.length; e < b; e++) {
      k = (p[f].link[e].rel == "alternate") ? p[f].link[e].href : "#"
    }
    d += '<div data-tag="'+c.feedsUri[c.current].tag+'" class="post hentry"' + (!c.autoHeight ? ' style="height' + c.thumbHeight + 'px;overflow:hidden; border-width:1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000; height: 200px"' : "") + ">";
    d += '<div class="post-title-2" style=" height: 38px;"><h2 style=" font-size: 13px; "><a href="' + k + '"' + (c.newTabLink ? ' target="_blank"' : "") + ">" + n + "</a></h2></div>";
    d += (c.showThumbnail) ? g : "";
    d += '<div class="summary">';
    d += "<span" + (!c.showSummary ? ' style="display:none;"' : "") + ">";
    d += (c.showSummary) ? m : "";
    d += "</span></div>";
    d += '<span style="display:block;clear:both;"></span></div>'
  }
  d += "";
  d += '<div class="more-link"><a href="' + c.feedsUri[c.current].url.replace(/\/$/, "") + "/search/label/" + c.feedsUri[c.current].tag + c.readMore.endParam + '"' + (c.newTabLink ? ' target="_blank"' : "") + ">" + c.readMore.text + "</a></div>";
  a.className = c.listClass;
  a.innerHTML = '<div data-tag=" margin-top: -33px;'+c.feedsUri[c.current].tag+'" +class="main-title"><h2>' + c.feedsUri[c.current].name + "</h2></div>" + d;
  h.appendChild(a);
  c.onLoadFeed(c.current);
  if((c.current + 1) < l) {
    c.loadFeed(c.current + 1)
  }
  if((c.current + 1) == l) {
    c.onLoadComplete()
  }
  c.current++
}
mf_defaults.loadFeed(0);
```

I believe that the party that is responsible for pulling the image is img

Comment: Why are you building the DOM using plain text string composition and innerHTML? That's a fantastic security bug right there. Use normal DOM methods (createElement, appendChild, etc, using a convenience package like jQuery or something if that feels too verbose) and set attributes with `setAttribute` and text content using `textContent`. Also, don't use 1998-style "on..." handlers directly in the HTML, use normal modern `addEventListsener` on real elements (which becomes a lot easier if you use normal DOM functions).

Comment: Missing a part of the code, I added it now

Comment: you have to fetch article body and this will reduce page speed score a lot. Or you might add the image at the first of all articles then parse article summary to get image attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a stupid answer... but from what I understand of your question, have you tried this?

```
g = ("media$thumbnail" in p[f]) ? '<img src="' + p[f].media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s72(\-c)?\//, "/w" + c.thumbWidth + "-h" + c.thumbHeight + "-c/") + '" style="width:' + c.thumbWidth + "px;height:" + c.thumbHeight + 'px;" title="' + n + '" alt="' + n + '">' : '';
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.